# Are M.S. degrees considered more "valuable" in the industry as compared to M. Eng degrees?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, masters, industry, engineering

Specifically in chemical or mechanical engineering. Are the M.S. degrees considered more "valuable" in the industry as compared to M. Eng? Where might having only an M. Eng. degree be a detriment in the industry? (Since I have no plans of pursuing a PhD)

Do these two degrees experience about the same approximate "pay bump" as compared to those people with only a B.S. ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about how a degree is perceived in the non-academic workplace. Experts in Academia are not the best people to answer this question; expert answers would come from those who routinely do hiring in your industry. See the [help/on-topic] for further details.